# How can I move Windows 10 bootloader (GUID) only to SD card?

Tags: boot, windows-10, ssd, uefi, bootloader

I have been trying to upgrade my laptop from a AHCI SSD to a much faster NVMe SSD without much success. I've pretty much concluded that my six month old Dell XPS 13 9343 doesn't have BIOS support for NVMe.

The Windows 10 installer has no problem seeing the NVMe SSD & the drive itself works - I just can't figure out a way to make it bootable. I am hoping to move my GUID bootloader to a SD card or USB stick but keep the core Windows 10 OS files on the SSD. Essentially I'm willing to put up with a slow boot (from SD card) to get the huge improvements in read/write speeds while Windows is running.

I don't understand the UEFI boot process well enough to get much traction with this.  How can I initiate the boot from a device that the BIOS sees as bootable while keeping the core OS files and most of the system writes on the SSD?

My laptop is a Dell XPS 13 9343 (2015), using a Samsung SM951 NVMe M.2 PCIe 3.0 256GB SSD.